# GCP Microservices in Different Clusters - High Latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices, cluster-computing, latency, vpc

I have two different clusters in different projects in the same region - Europe-west1 region, **but they are in a shared VPC**. I have a microservice (M1) deployed in one cluster (C1) and within the application, I am making a call to the other microservice (M2) in the other cluster (C2). And i am using Ingress service for exposing M2. But still I am getting a high latency around 40-50ms, as opposed to the normal 5-6 ms. Is this because of the applications being is different clusters (they are in the same shared VPC though). Would deploying them in the same cluster help? Would using a pool of connections help in reducing latency, or a persistent connection kind of thing, as most of the time is being taken up in opening the connection to M2.

Comment: In your case, traffic is actually reaching the M2 service through the Internet as it's been exposed via Ingress (External HTTP LB). In this case, though both the clusters reside in the same region, traffic is taking an external path, therefore the latency might vary due to ISP network(hops it takes to reach the destination).You may perform a test on your side, which is to create two new test VMs in your two clusters, make communication and then record the latency,and then compare the results.

Comment: If you notice normal network performance then this will rule out an issue with the network,  then it might be the application in the cluster or cluster configuration causing the issue.
Deploying them in the same cluster(within the same shared VPC) and making communication with internal IPs, may reduce the latency, as in this case, traffic will remain in google’s internal network. I am also interested to know if you are using GKE[1] or it’s your self managed kubernetes micro service.”
[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine

Comment: Does Ingress always cause the traffic to come through Internet (External path), even when it is a private address

Comment: And what about if I deploy the two services (M1 and M2) in the same cluster and use the Cluster IP of M2 when calling from M1?

Comment: hey, can you please reply

Comment: Can you tell us more about your “ingress service” that exposed your M2 service? Are you using an ingress like external [ingress HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)or [internal TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) or any other [service type](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps). As well to address your queries better, can you tell us, if your service M2 is exposed through an external IP or internal IP?

Comment: As you mentioned microservice M1 is making calls to microcervice M2, we need to know the total network architecture from source to destination (all the products involved in the solution like VPCs, GCE instances, GKE cluster, nodes, services, etc.). We need to know if the source and destination IPs are private/public. At the same time, a MTR test(from source to destination) result could help us to see the hops it takes to reach the destination. Examining the hops will help us to understand if the traffic remains in Google’s network or traveling over the transit ISP.